# Chrome url bar vs 100vh with css

Tags: html, css

I tried to understand how `css env` works but I cannot... I have problem with my sidebar and chrome search bar that hides after page scrolls down a bit. Otherwise using `100vh` for my sidebar with scroll, some content stays hidden under the page so user needs to scroll page to scroll sidebar to the bottom of it.

I tried using these but I do not understand them either way:

```
height: env(safe-area-inset-top, calc(100vh - 56px));
```

And as I found somewhere, 56 is for phone size, but where is tablet size bar etc?

Is there actual solution for this? Without using media for displays and setting different heights?

Comment: as it is, your question is a bit too broad. Please have a look at [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env). What you are looking for is the fallback property. In particular, `A CSS environment variable is accessed using the env() notation. This notation accepts two values - the variable name, and a fallback value for if the variable wasn’t found.` ([reference](https://bitsofco.de/css-environment-variables/)).

Comment: The url bar is not included in the viewport. Not sure this makes sense.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Well in 100vh on my phone now on chrome I  dont see part of sidebar same size of chrome searchbar...